# Magento custom module not connecting to Observer.php file

Tags: php, magento, module

I've been trying for the last few days to get a custom module working for creating tooltips on the available variations for our product pages. I've largely followed the tutorial from this site: http://gielberkers.com/add-custom-properties-magento-attributes/

I've been able to create a new row in the database to input a tooltip under `catalog_eav_attributes` but I can't get the field to show up in the admin panel of Magento with the `Observer.php` file. I've tried everything I can think of. Here's my files:

`app/etc/modules/Feature_Tooltip.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>                       
    <modules>
        <Feature_Tooltip>
            <active>true</active>           
            <codePool>local</codePool>      
        </Feature_Tooltip>
    </modules>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Feature/Tooltip/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Feature_Tooltip>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Feature_Tooltip>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <feature_tooltip>
                <class>Feature_Tooltip_Model</class>
            </feature_tooltip>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <tooltip_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Feature_Tooltip</module>
                    <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                </setup>
            </tooltip_setup>
        </resources>
            <events>
                <adminhtml_catalog_product_attribute_edit_prepare_form>
                    <observers>
                        <feature_tooltip_model_observer>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>feature_tooltip/observer</class>
                            <method>addFieldToAttributeEditForm</method>
                        </feature_tooltip_model_observer>
                    </observers>
                </adminhtml_catalog_product_attribute_edit_prepare_form>
            </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Feature/Tooltip/Model/Observer.php`

```
<?php
exit; //I've only got this in here to test whether it's even reaching the Observer.php file. So far no luck.                                                                                                                                                                             
class Feature_Tooltip_Model_Observer 
{
   /**
    * Hook that allows us to edit the form that is used to create and/or edit attributes.
    * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
    */                         
   public function addFieldToAttributeEditForm($observer)
   {
       // Add an extra field to the base fieldset:
       $fieldset = $observer->getForm()->getElement('base_fieldset');
       $fieldset->addField('tooltip', 'text', array(
           'name' => 'tooltip',
           'label' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Tooltip'),
           'title' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Tooltip')
       ));
   }
}
```

Any suggestions are very welcome. I've run out of ideas.

Comment: Are you sure the observer event is being dispatched with dispatchEvent()?  And the <class> for the observer in the config file should be written long form, I believe. `<class>Feature_Tooltip_Model_Observer</class>` not `<class>feature_tooltip/observer</class>`

Comment: Thanks RagingCelt! That was all it was. I switched the name in the <class> tag and everything is working. I figured it was something small, but I just couldn't get it.